# how to get preceding-sibling to work in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Given this XML:

```
<Table>
  <ID>3589</ID>
  <Type>Change Request</Type>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Summary>...</Summary>
</Table>
<Table>
  <ID>3596</ID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Type>Change Request</Type>
  <Summary>...</Summary>
</Table>
<Table>
  <ID>4818</ID>
  <Type>Bug</Type>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Summary>...</Summary>
</Table>
<Table>
  <ID>4819</ID>
  <Type>Bug</Type>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Summary>...</Summary>
</Table>
<Table>
  <ID>4820</ID>
  <Type>Bug</Type>
  <Version>2</Version>
  <Summary>...</Summary>
</Table>
```

I use this XSLT:

```
...
<xsl:for-each select="//Table[Version=$vn]">
  <xsl:sort select="Type" />
   <xsl:variable name="currentType" select="Type" />
   <xsl:if test="not($currentType=preceding-sibling::Table/Type)">
      <h2><xsl:value-of select="Type" /></h2>
   </xsl:if>
   <p><b><xsl:value-of select="ID" /></b>:<xsl:value-of select="Summary" /></p>
</xsl:for-each>
...
```

What test do I need to use to only show Type when it changes? I only want te first occurence to show. Right now preceding-sibling::Table/Type always refers to the first 'row'

The transformation is done in C#.

Comment: I don't see a Version element under Table

Comment: Will the Types always be grouped together, or can they repeat? i.e Can you have "Change Request", "Change Request", "Bug", "Bug", ""Change Request"? If they can repeat, what would you want to see?

Comment: For each Version (missing element in the sample XML) they repeat.

Comment: Can you amend your XML sample to include the Version element as it sounds like it is actually relevant to the question? Thanks!

Comment: I updated the question altough the answer from xaioyi did help me out already. But perhaps there is a more elegant or better answer. You never know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
<xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::Table[Version=$vn][Type=$currentType])">
```

Comment: @amaters oops, this one should work now, but not sure [Version=$vn] part is needed or not.